# How costly server-side Blazor is?

Tags: signalr, blazor

Server-side Blazor maintains connection to the server-side apparently, using SignalR.
SignalR is the service you need to pay for. As many simultaneous connections to SignalR are going to be used as many online users your app has at the moment of time.

Do I understand correctly, that I will need to pay for next SignalR tier once I reach certain SignalR free tier limit? And **only because I use Blazor**, not that I use SignalR for other purposes.

And two cost-reduction alternatives are:

- use client-side Blazor WebAssembly
- don't use Blazor at all

Comment: SignalR is not mandatory. If you have taken an azure appservice subscription, the number of connections is only limited by the server capability. AFAIK, the separate SignalR hub subscription is required only when you want to use it to achieve a geographically distributed scale.

Answer (score 0):

We run 3 instances of P3V3 app service to serve ~450 users (it is a LOB app, so open by most users, most of the day)

Our SignalR service cost is double the app service plan.

You can use signalr over websockets instead of the SignalR service, but for some unknown reason it is unstable and you'll see lots of signalr connection drop outs.

There's no way to save costs on SignalR - no reservations, no bulk discounts.